# Getting Application.CommonAppDataPath and UserAppDataPath in ApplicationEvents Startup

Tags: vb.net, startup

I would like to set the default location for some files on Application Startup, but in the ApplicationEvents' `MyApplication_Startup` sub I can't seem to get the `Application.CommonAppDataPath` and `Application.UserAppDataPath` variables.

Is there any way around this? Without hard coding of course.

Comment: " I cant seem to get the Application.CommonAppDataPath and Application.UserAppDataPath variables" can you elaborate please?

Comment: Those are Read-only properties, so you cant change them ("set the default").  Not clear what you are asking since you may not have access to all the app variables in `Application.Startup` et al.  `Environment.GetFolderPath()` will allow you to create path locations

Comment: In ApplicationEvents.vb, the variable Application.CommonAppDataPath and Application.UserAppDataPath are not available.  I am not able to use them for setting up application resources.

Comment: what does "setting up application resources" mean?  This is why code illustrating the problem is important in questions.

Comment: Alex, they are indeed available. See my answer.

Comment: May I be so rude and ask why I have not received even a little comment on my answer? Isn't working, or have you not had the time to test it yet? :)

Comment: Sorry about that, work sent me on an emergency support trip, I will be able to try implementing this this weekend.

Comment: No problem, please take your time. -- The reason I asked is because there's been situations where I've answered a question but received no response from the asker for a vey long time... It just makes me a bit stressed _(now that I know your situation it doesn't matter though :) )_.

Comment: I've actually been in the situation where an asker took 6 months to mark my post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` in the main part of your project (in your own forms, classes, etc.) refers to the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class. *However* under the `MyApplication` class (or more specifically the `My` namespace) it refers to `<your namespace>.My.Application` (which is the same as `My.Application`).

This happens because the framework's classes and objects are shadowed by your project's local objects. In this case the framework's `Application` class is shadowed by the project's `My.Application` property.

You simply need to add the namespace in the beginning:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.CommonAppDataPath
System.Windows.Forms.Application.UserAppDataPath
```